# Craft 3 Plugin not returning custom field value

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am trying to get the value of a custom field in entries, but I can't seem to get it to grab that value. I'm assuming I'm pulling it too early or too late, otherwise I have no idea.

I can pull the value the of the lightswitch `enabled`

```
Event::on(Elements::class, Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) 
    {
        $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();

        // will successfully send email if enabled lightswitch is on
        if($request->getBodyParam('enabled') == 1)
        {
            $html = $request->getBodyParam('enabled');
            $subject = "testing";
            $mail = "example@gmail.com";
            return $this->sendMail($html, $subject, $mail);
        }
    });
```

The below doesn't return anything at all for the custom field `fields[sendEmail]`

```
Event::on(Elements::class, Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) 
    {
        $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();

        // will not send email no matter what position the lightswitch is in
        if($request->getBodyParam('fields[sendEmail]') == 1)
        {
            $html = $request->getBodyParam('fields[sendEmail]');
            $subject = "testing";
            $mail = "example@gmail.com";
            return $this->sendMail($html, $subject, $mail);
        }
    });
```

I tried changing the event handler to `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT` but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/web/Request.php)

```
// get $_POST['foo']['bar'], if it exists
$bar = Craft::$app->request->getBodyParam('foo.bar');
```

or inserting it into my code

```
Event::on(Elements::class, Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) 
{
    $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();

    if($request->getBodyParam('fields.sendEmail') == 1)
    {
        $html = $request->getBodyParam('fields.sendEmail');
        $subject = "testing";
        $mail = "example@gmail.com";
        $this->sendMail($html, $subject, $mail);
    }
});
```

Comment: If someone wants to expand on this I'd be happy to select someone else's contribution as top answer, such as a possible better way of doing this.

Comment: Just occurred to me my answer above isn't complete. While it did accomplish what I asked, `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT` is for any element being saved, which means I have to find a way to determine what element is being saved.